# Razor and C# ViewData being used as a select list. The selected item changes when page loads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the following C# code to create a select list.

```
ViewData["companyList"] = new SelectList(
        db.companies.Where(ai => true), "id", "companyName", domain.companyId
    );
```

When I step through the code the ViewData context has the correct item selected (the secod item in the list).

The razor has the following:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.companyId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.companyId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["companyList"], new { @class = "apex-select-list" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyId)
    </div>

public partial class company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public short status { get; set; }
    public int location911Id { get; set; }
    public int timeoffsetid { get; set; }
    public int creatorId { get; set; }
    public int modifiedById { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated { get; set; }
}

public partial class domain
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string domainName { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public int creatorId { get; set; }
    public int modifiedById { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated { get; set; }
}
```

When the page is displayed it always is defaulting to the first item as selected.  I have viewed the page source and is clearly chows the first item as selected not what was shown as selected in the debugger.

I have used this construct many times and never had a problem.

How could this happen?

Comment: Can you show company model?

Comment: have you debuged to see if your `domain.companyId` has the value that you want to show, maybe its 0 at that moment.

Comment: yes the comanyId is 1.  When the ViewData is inspected it has the correct list item selected as well.  It is when the View is diaplayed that the incorrect selected item appears.

Comment: then maybe some javascript is changing that to the default value. Your code looks just fine.

Comment: Seichi great insight but there isn't any javascript changing the value.  I just verified that in they debugger. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewData["companyList"] = new SelectList(
    db.companies.AsEnumerable(), "companyId", "companyName", domain.companyId
);
```

It looks like you have the wrong dataValueField param since companies presumably has no column named `id` but does have a column named `companyId`.

Comment: no the table companies does have a field of id.  the domain.companyId comes from a different table and is used to "Select" the correct company.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine and should work that way, but if the default value is shown could it be for:

1) Some javascript is changing the value to the default value.

2) The value from domain.companyId does not belong to the list

```
 db.companies.Where(ai => true)
```

Comment: Again thanks for the response but I just stepped through the javascript debugger and nothing is changing that select.  The value is in the companies table and is shown correctly in the c# debugger.